# How to set width in Ext.grid.ColumnModel in percentage terms?

Tags: extjs, grid, column-width

How to set width in `Ext.grid.ColumnModel` in percentage terms?

Answer (score 9):

Use numbers for the column widths with a total of 100 and configure the view with forceFit, e.g.

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
     cm: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
          columns: [{
              header: 'header1',
              dataIndex: 'data1',
              width: 30
          },{
              header: 'header2',
              dataIndex: 'data2',
              width: 30
         },{
              header: 'header3',
              dataIndex: 'data3',
              width: 40
         }]
     }),
     viewConfig: {
          forceFit: true
     }
});
```

Comment: If you're not going to change the column definitions you might be better off using `viewConfig: { autoFill: true }` instead, see [sencha 3 docs](http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.2.0/docs/)